# Multi-module android application with Dagger2 without using `kapt` in the feature module

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, module, dagger-2

I have an Android application with the following setup:

2 gradle modules: `app` and `feature` (just started modularising and this is the first feature module of many)

In the feature module `FeatureModule` which is a Dagger `@Module` providing dependencies for the feature.

In the `app` module `AppComponent` handling all the dependencies, having a reference to the `FeatureModule` (`@Component(modules = [...,FeatureModule::class])`)

This is working fine. The problem is that I need these lines in both of the module's `build.gradle`s:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
....
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.22.1'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22.1'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.22.1'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.22.1'
```

As far as I know, adding `kapt` to all the feature modules slows the build down significantly (I might be wrong on this tho).
So I only want to have these lines in the feature module's `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.22.1'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22.1'
```

This might be a different topic but I'm gonna ask it anyways. Do you think I should create a separate `@Component` for the feature module (and the other feature modules to come) or is it enough to have a separate Dagger `@Module` for them?

Actually I tried to create a `@Component`, but I only found examples about it for the `@Component.Builder` setup and I'm using the new `@Component.Factory` one.

The only reason why I'm considering the component is so that I could give a different `@Scope` for the feature, but I don't think I want to do that now. Do you know about any other reason for me to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keeping the dependencies unscoped or scoped to your singleton appcomponent is fine for now. Introduce custom scopes when you have a standard setup for your features. As for kapt, yes, generating code does slow down the build. For that you can look into [dagger-reflect](https://github.com/JakeWharton/dagger-reflect). Use dagger-reflect for dev builds and google dagger for release/staging builds. Fast compilation in dev builds and compile-time safety in release builds. Win-win

Comment: Hi @sonnet and thanks for your answer!
I didn't know about this library, it looks promising but it's in a 0.2 version now and adding it to our project seems a bit dangerous at this point. But if I understand it correctly, if I'm using dagger I can't have a dagger `@Module` in the gradle module without introducing the `kapt` dependency to it, right?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible but I was able to do the following workaround.

You should replace `implementation` in the core module with `api`. So your code will look like this,

core `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
....
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22.1'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.22.1'
```

feature `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
....
implementation project(':core')
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.22.1'
```